# avoid Race condition between the azure continuous delivery

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I am deploying DEV environment in two pipelines that contains (Deployment(10 mins) + tests run on deplyment (10mins) post deployment) for each run.

```
1>Master Pipeline - Triggers when changes merged to master
2>Release Pipeline - Manual deployment
```

During deployment to Release pipeline if some code merged to master then pipeline will trigger & error message some other installation/upgrade in progress & lead to fail state.

If deployment in Same pipeline then the deployment waits for previous one completes & starts deployment but as my tests running in previous deployment this would also lead to error prone scenario.

is there any dependency can be achieved in Azure delivery step between two CD pipelines if deployment going on one environment then other Release from different pipeline should wait ?

Answer (score 0):

- Since you want to invoke a `deployment pipeline` after the execution
  of a `testing pipeline` what you can do that inside the test pipeline
  before the start of the testing use a task to invoke a function which
  will store (inside a storage solution of your choice) the status of the `test pipeline` as under execution.
- Then after the completion of testing the `test pipeline` again
  trigger a function which will reset the status of the `test pipeline`
  to completed execution.
- Then inside the `development pipeline` you can create a `GATE`  at
  the start of the pipeline . This gate will invoke a function which
  will check for the test pipeline status and return a response to the
  gate . Now this gate will not start the deployment until a preferred
  response is received (i.e. the test pipeline has completed execution) from the function.
- Use agentless job to trigger the functions in the pipelines.

**Reference:**

Refer this [article](https://www.marcusfelling.com/blog/2019/trigger-an-azure-function-powershell-from-an-azure-devops-pipeline/#:%7E:text=%20Trigger%20an%20Azure%20Function%20%28PowerShell%29%20from%20an,outlines%20just%20one%20of%20many%20script...%20More%20) by Marcus  Felling to trigger function using agent less jobs  .

[Azure Pipeline GATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/gates?view=azure-devops)